# How To Convert Txt file into .Rdata format

Tags: python, r, twitter

I am using my python script and Tweepy to collect tweets and extract only text portion.  I saved all the texts from these tweets in txt format.

I am now trying to load this text in R for textual analysis using this module (http://rpubs.com/gogamza/ko_text_mining)  However, this R module only accepts .Rdata files, and I somehow need to feed my tweet collection onto R.

The R code says:

```
library(twitteR)
# n <- 200
# 
# keyword <- '삼성전자'
# 
# keyword <- enc2utf8(keyword)
# 
# rdmTweets <- searchTwitter(keyword, n)

load(url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8686172/twitter.RData"))

nDocs <- length(rdmTweets)
```

So, inside the load command, I'd like to add my own text file there.
Can someone offer me a tip?  Thanks a lot.. I'd appreciate it so much.

Comment: Does just renaming it work, or is .Rdata more complex than that?

Comment: I tried renaming it, but it won't work.  I think the structure is flat out different

Comment: `.Rdata` is more complex than that. Have you tried using `read.table`?

Comment: No, I haven't, but does that turn text into R data frame?

Comment: yes it does. You probably want read.table.

Comment: You can read csv (or similar) files using `rdmTweets <- read.table("filename.txt")`. If your file contains only one column, you could also do `rdmTweets <- data.frame(text=readLines("filename.txt"))`. However, the data frame `rdmTweets` in your example contains several columns: text, favorited, replyToSN, created, truncated, replyToSID, id, replyToUID, statusSource and screenName. I don't know how far you will get with only the text column... Perhaps it would be better to uncomment the `#` lines and do everything in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data in your txt file in R and save it as an RData file:

```
sapply(list.files("/folderWithFiles", pattern="*.txt", full.names = TRUE),
       function(x) { myDataInVector = scan(x, what=character()); save(myDataInVector, file=gsub("\\.txt","\\.RData",x))  } )
```

The reading in part `scan(x, what=character())` assumes you have your data in all in the text file as a space delimited vector. You can use read.table or change the arguments of the scan command if it is in a different format.